# Determining which users uploaded an image?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, scripting, mysql5

I have a database of users that I have allowed to upload their images to their profiles. There is no indication in the database that each has uploaded an image to their profile and that is exactly what I need to know.

Is there any way that I could determine this for the users in the db have already taken the action to upload an image?

All ideas are welcome on this one. Really need to know in order to prompt those that haven't when they login.

Thanks~

Comment: How are you displaying the picture?  If you don't have a picture to display, then you could alert them?

Comment: How does the code in php then know which picture to display?

Comment: How are you allowing them to upload an image? Can't you capture their userid and record that in the database?

Comment: Probably not possible for items you already in your database (although it is impossible for us to say without being able to look at your db and your code). But you can modify this so you record a user id for the future.

Comment: Have a default profile image that just reads "Why not upload your own photo"?

Comment: Don't forget that if you like somebody's answer you can mark it as accepted, by clicking on check near the answer

Comment: This is WAY to vague. I'm surprised you got anything. In the future, please provide code and context in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the image to a user.
One way to do this is by adding a user_id key to your images.
Retroactively if there is no logs or traces of which user uploaded the image then no.  But from here on out you can set up your db to keep track of this.

Comment: @Charlieg & dm03514, thank you guys! This makes sense to me but I have one more question.  What would you do with people that have already uploaded their images?

Answer (score 1):

We really need some more information on your website's code and db structure. How is the image stored? What does the script that displays the user's image do? How is the image mapped to the user in the first place?

What you need to do is the same thing the script that displays the profile image is doing. 
Put another field in your db that can store whether or not the user has uploaded an image. Then, write another script that can go through each of your users and (using the same method that is used when displaying the profile image) check if the user's profile image is the default. If it is not, update the new field in your db for that user.

Make sure that you update your code so that any new uploads also update this new field.

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean in your database when they initially upload a photo (and change it whenever, such as if they delete the photo) and then check that boolean to see if you should display a prompt or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have users on your website, it means that you can track logged in users by their cookies or sessions.

When user sign in, php script should create an unique cookie value for every user and place it to the database, then it reads the cookie or session and check what user has this cookie or session.

To detect what user uploaded an image, you can place to your picture table column named `image_path` and store there a path to the uploaded image. Add to the same table column which identify the user.

Exactly after uploading:

`UPDATE your_table SET image_path='$path to the image' WHERE ..#then user identifier in the second column`